# Updating a table with record type object

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a table say `EMPLOYER` with `EMPLOYER_ID` as the primary key. I write the following script to update a row in the table:

```
declare
    emp_row EMPLOYER%ROWTYPE;
begin
    select * into emp_row from EMPLOYER where rownum <= 1;
    emp_row.NAME := 'ABC';
    emp_row.AGE  := 99;
    -- Can I write something like below?
    update EMPLOYER set ??? = emp_row where EMPLOYER_ID = emp_row.EMPLOYER_ID;
end;
```

Can I update a row with a record type object in a single statement? Just as shown in the example above.

Comment: Please provide full question

Comment: The question is already updated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please try something like this

```
update EMPLOYER set ROW = emp_row where EMPLOYER_ID = emp_row.EMPLOYER_ID;
```

Remember: this UPDATE sets the value of every column in the table, including your primary key, so you should use the SET ROW syntax with great care.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can:

```
declare
    emp_row EMPLOYER%ROWTYPE;
begin
    select * into emp_row from EMPLOYER where rownum <= 1;
    emp_row.NAME := 'ABC';
    emp_row.AGE  := 99;
    update EMPLOYER e set row = emp_row
    where e.EMPLOYER_ID = emp_row.EMPLOYER_ID;
end;
```

However, be aware that this will attempt to update EVERY column in the row, including the primary key. Also, if your table ever gets a virtual column, this will fail.

Answer (score 0):

To answer you question: 
You need to update every column with for example: `ColumnA = recordName.ColumnA`, you can not insert a whole line at once.

To give you an advice: 
 
The `SELECT INTO` is kinda dangerous I think, becasue if your table is empty you will try to insert a NULL value, what will result in the following error: `ORA-01403: no data found`. 
That error can realy hard to find in bigger projects.

Maybe this example will give you an idea: 
Here I use a cursor to fetch the rows from a table. 
Because I don't loop through them only the first record found is taken and stored in `rEmployer`. 
So `rEmpoyer` conatins all data from the first rownumber from that table.

I use a boolean to check if there is some data found, and if we did we put it on `TRUE`. 
After that we update the table.

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR cEmployer IS 
        SELECT  * 
        FROM    Employer;

    rEmployer   cEmployer%ROWTYPE;
    fFound      BOOLEAN := FALSE;
BEGIN
    -- By not using a loop, only the first record is taken.
    OPEN cEmployer;
    FETCH cEmployer INTO rEmployer;
    IF cEmployer%FOUND THEN
        -- There is a row in the table 'Employer'. 
        fFound := TRUE;
    END IF;
    CLOSE cTemp;

    -- Modify some values and add update the row:
    IF fFound THEN 
        -- MOdify some values.
        rEmployer.Name := 'ABC';
        rEmployer.Age := '99';

        -- Update the table. 
        UPDATE  Employer
        SET     Name = rEmployer.Name,
            Age = rEmployer.Age
        WHERE   EmployerId = rEmployer.EmployerId;

        COMMIT;
    END IF;
END;
/
```